# How to generate SSL Certificate in Php code, and what are the requirements

Tags: php, ssl

I have been searching around for hours and days, trying to understand what files is required in order to use free ssl for my website, but im getting confused, please explain what file or folder are required and where they should be located in file manager.

I have manage to generate codes for CSR private and public keys, but I'm not sure if I'm doing them right or in the right file extension and where they should be located.

Please if someone can explain one by one with clear answer, I would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are exposing that you already make your research... What did you try? Where are you stuck? If you did not begin with your own work, that is not your forum.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGarcíaBodego for the reply, I need to know how to connect the CSR codes with SSL and where to locat them in which folder, the CSR files that i have are .key and .pem, are they the correct files for CSR, and do i need more files for CSR, and what files are required from SSL.

Comment: I am not getting your point. With the CSR, you have the application in order to get a SSL certificate. It depends on which platform are you using. Check [this](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1229769)

Comment: I'm using Openssl to get the SSL certificate.

Comment: So follow [this](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1221018-generate-csr---openssl)

Comment: Thanks David García Bodego for the reply, however this doesn’t short out my issue because, first in my post I said I want to create free SSL certificate using PHP, since I have already created CSR I was checking if I have created in right way and if the files that I have in CSR are all I need, and how to generate SSL from CSR in php. Thanks